# What are the best practices regarding SSR, Django and temprarly changed data?

Tags: django, orm, server-side-rendering, htmx

I'm currently building a Django app using htmx. It's something like a journal with multiple entries per day. When a user changes one entry or adds another I don't want to store the data just yet in case the user cancels the input. This is no problem for a single change but when there are multiple changes it gets overly complicated because the current state is only correctly represented on the website and not in the DB object anymore.

What would be the best practice to handle this problem? I'm using function based views, not classes. I'm thinking about adding a temporary object table where a copy of my journal week/days is added and changed and gets deleted after the user saves the real object. Is there a better way to do it?